# Display html markup in react jsx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

Wanted to display straight up html markup into my template.

Here is the file where I am writing html code that I want to display. I want to display all the html elements.

```
import React from 'react';

const html = (
  <div>
      <ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
);

export default html
```

**component file**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import html from './code/htmlCodeSnippet';

...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {html}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am importing that html file to be displayed in my component. I will be using an html highlighter to display the code.

Whenever I reference `{html}`, it doesnt show all the html elements. It just shows as

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: How are you sure it's not displaying the div tag?

Comment: @lakerskill What do you mean? Because when i look at the page, none of the elements are being shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to make few changes. first change `html` to a string i.e

```
const html = `
   <div>
      <ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
         <li>5</li>
      </ul>
      <p>hello</p>
  </div>`;
```

And use `pre` and `code` elements to wrap `html` in render method i.e

`<pre><code>{html}</code></pre>`