# How to display the html of the children slot?

Tags: reactjs

I've got this react component where I'm passing in a title and the children is a simple div with the word test.

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <SourceCode title="Header">
          <div>test</div>
        </SourceCode>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to display the HTML of whatever is in the children slot so in this example I want to to show `<div>test</div>`, I've tried using `pre` but I get the error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

```
export default function SourceCode({ children, title }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>{children}</div> // <== Here I want to render the markup, this works
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(children)}</pre> // <== Here I want to show the markup
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also tried

```
      <pre>
          <code>{children}</code>
        </pre>
```

but this just shows `test` and I want it to show  `<div>test</div>`

Comment: To clarify, you mean to show the actual markup on the page instead of having React render the markup?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to show the markup, I don't want to render the markup, I've managed to render it in the second div, but in the third div I want to show the markup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display html markup in react jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381107/display-html-markup-in-react-jsx)

Comment: `<pre><code>{children}</code></pre>` just renders the word `test` but I want it to show `<div>test</div>`

Comment: I tried it but no, its doesn't, I edited my question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup)

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

export default function SourceCode({ children, title }) {
  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(children);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>{children}</div> // <== Here I want to render the markup, this works
      <div>
        <pre>{markup}</pre> // <== Here I want to show the markup
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this looks promising where does ReactDOMServer come from? typescript is giving me `Cannot find name 'ReactDOMServer'.ts(2304)` I've tried `import { ReactDOMServer } from "react";`

Comment: @Bill I updated my answer with the import

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect